# Example of a function on a compact domain whose derivative is unbounded.

Tags: real-analysis

I was wondering if there is any function on $[a,b]$ to real line, such that $f'$ is unbounded. If anyone can produce a particular example of this fact, will be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it need to be onto?

Comment: No!@ Adriab Keister. I was stuck to this point to prove some result in Fourier Analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I$ be any interval $[a,b]$ containing $0$. On the interval $I$ define $f(x) = |x|^{3/2}\sin {1 \over x}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The standard example of a differentiable function with a discontinuous derivative works here. Choose $c\in[a,b]$ and let $$f(x)=\begin{cases}(x-c)^2\sin(1/(x-c)^2),&(x\ne c),\\0,&(x=c).\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ does not need to be onto, then $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ works. Its derivative is $f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}},$ which is unbounded at the origin.

Comment: Does $f'(0)$ exist?

Comment: No, it doesn't. The question was to produce a function whose derivative is unbounded, and $1/\left(2\sqrt{x}\right)$ is unbounded.

Comment: I would guess the intention was to find a function differentiable on $[a,b]$ with unbounded derivative.

Comment: Hard to know exactly what the OPer wants, as there haven't been any responses to questions.